# Incorrect syntax near ','. Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to implement the solution [outlined in this article](https://www.essentialsql.com/create-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server/) but am getting the error below. Since this code is newish to me, I'm struggling to find the offending comma. Line 10 is the first WHERE statement. If I highlight and run rows 1-11, I do not get any errors.

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ','."

```
DECLARE
@Columns as VARCHAR(MAX),
@SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
FROM
   (select distinct (ColumnName)
        FROM vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data INNER JOIN
            vw_Base_Batch_Events ON vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ReferenceInteger = vw_Base_Batch_Events.ReferenceInteger
                    where (EventType IN ('NONCONF', 'REJECT', 'SKIP')) AND (MachineNumber LIKE '5999%') AND (LogDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-06-30 00:00:00', 102))) AS B
ORDER BY B.ColumnName

SET @SQL = 'SELECT HydraBatch, MESOrderNumber, MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(
select vw_Base_Batch_Events.MESOrderNumber, vw_Base_Batch_Events.HydraBatch,vw_Base_Batch_Events.MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch, vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.Entry,vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ColumnName,vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ColumnValue
FROM            vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data INNER JOIN
                         vw_Base_Batch_Events ON vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ReferenceInteger = vw_Base_Batch_Events.ReferenceInteger
where (EventType IN ("NONCONF", "REJECT", "SKIP")) AND (MachineNumber LIKE "5999%") AND (LogDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, "2019-06-01 00:00:00", 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, "2019-06-30 00:00:00", 102))
) as PivotData
PIVOT
(max(MESOrderNumber),Max(HydraBatch), Max(MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch)
FOR ColumnName in (' + @Columns + ')
) as PivotResult
ORDER BY MESOrderNumber, HydraBatch'

exec(@SQL);
```

EDIT: Printing @SQL returns the following.

```
SELECT HydraBatch, MESOrderNumber, MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch, [Comment], [Line], [LineTechnician], [PartDescription], [PartNo], [ReasonId], [ReasontextText], [ReportedAt], [ReportedBy], [SignedOfByFinalizer], [SignedOfByQA], [SignedOffFinalizerAt], [SignedOffQAAt], [Station]
FROM
(
select vw_Base_Batch_Events.MESOrderNumber, vw_Base_Batch_Events.HydraBatch,vw_Base_Batch_Events.MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch, vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.Entry,vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ColumnName,vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ColumnValue
FROM            vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data INNER JOIN
                         vw_Base_Batch_Events ON vw_PZD_Detail_DLG_Data.ReferenceInteger = vw_Base_Batch_Events.ReferenceInteger
where (EventType IN ("NONCONF", "REJECT", "SKIP")) AND (MachineNumber LIKE "5999%") AND (LogDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, "2019-06-01 00:00:00", 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, "2019-06-30 00:00:00", 102))
) as PivotData
PIVOT
(max(MESOrderNumber),Max(HydraBatch), Max(MaterialNumberInputOrOutputBatch)
FOR ColumnName in ([Comment], [Line], [LineTechnician], [PartDescription], [PartNo], [ReasonId], [ReasontextText], [ReportedAt], [ReportedBy], [SignedOfByFinalizer], [SignedOfByQA], [SignedOffFinalizerAt], [SignedOffQAAt], [Station])
) as PivotResult
ORDER BY MESOrderNumber, HydraBatch
```

Comment: Can you print the content of `@SQL` ?

Comment: It looks like @Columns will start with a ',' which shouldn't be there.

Comment: At first glance looks ok, do you try that @SQL direct on the db? Got same error? My suggestion is simplify the query until you get a result and then add more complexity, and then get back to build the dynamic query

Comment: The issue was having three Max statements after the pivot, it seems. When I reduce it to one, I don't get any errors. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You cant have multiple aggregations for pivot.